# Spyder console not showing output

Tags: python, spyder

I run the following code in Spyder 4.1.1 but the console doesn't show any output :

```
df.head()
df.shape
```

Previously I had Spyder 3.7 and it worked but now after updating it is not working. I tried resetting to default settings and tried to change the console settings but nothing worked. If I used print(df.head) it works but it should work without print().

Please help. Attached is the screenshot

[spyder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqeK8.jpg)

Comment: "but it should work without print()." - nah, it shouldn't. That's just how interactive consoles often work, but it's not defined by the specification. Just print or learn logging.

Comment: So why it worked in Spyder 3.7 and why not now ? Jupiter notebook also works the same.You don't have to add print() to see the output.

Comment: If you think this is needed, consider commenting on Spyder's project. We're not Spyder's developers.

Comment: I agree with h4z3, it shouldn't work. That's why we removed that for Spyder 4, because it leads to false expectations when running code outside Spyder.

Answer (score 4):

Try running the following in the Ipython console.

```
%config InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity='last_expr'
```

This is the setting description:

```
ZMQInteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity=<Enum>

Current: 'last_expr'
Choices: ['all', 'last', 'last_expr', 'none', 'last_expr_or_assign']

'all', 'last', 'last_expr' or 'none', 'last_expr_or_assign' specifying which 
nodes should be run interactively (displaying output from expressions).
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to highlight what you want to run.
Then run/execute the current line/s by either pressing `F9`, or the `Run selection or current line` button on the `Run toolbar`(the black one). 
It will then show output without needing to use `print`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but opening a new console and rerunning the code with the F9 key fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

First, use print(x), or plt.show() if using matplotlib.pyplot.

Then, if you find that spyder python does not give any output at  (F5),  change Preferences (spanner icon), select menu 'Run' and change to a different Console option, e.g. 'Execute in a dedicated console', then Run (F5).

As a newbie and very occasional user I regularly have this frustrating problem of how to run the code to get a pyplot output - I press the green play button and nothing happens! No charts, until I change those preferences.

Comment: This problem of python not showing output is a common question across the internet. I suspect this arises from people like myself coming from engineering and science, who are migrating to python (away from mathcad, excel, matlab) to do scientific computing. We want a simple workflow that gets outputs. The workflow needs to be stable so that as occasional users we are not disadvantaged by falling back down the learning curve. We  are not interested in consoles and kernels - that's machinery that should just work, not put barriers into the workflow.